Unable to render status/500 page, the template system is broken, or Gitea can't find your template files
After setting up Forgejo and attempting to run it locally using go run main.go, I encountered the following error when visiting localhost:3000:

Unable to render status/500 page, the template system is broken, or
Gitea can't find your template files.

Interestingly, when I compile it first with go build main.go and then run it, the issue doesn't occur. There is already a post similar to mine on the internet but the provided solution is not working for me since I'm not running any other services on my system.
Does anyone have any insights into why this might be happening?
For reference, my setup process includes the following steps:
npm install
go mod tidy
make clean
make frontend
make backend

And this is the full error I'm getting:

2024/10/02 13:31:26 .../i18n/localestore.go:131:TrString() [E] Missing translation "install.install"
2024/10/02 13:31:26 .../context_response.go:91:HTML() [E] Render failed: failed to render template: install, error: asset from: , template "install" not found
2024/10/02 13:31:26 ...eb/routing/logger.go:102:func1() [I] router: completed GET / for [::1]:61953, 200 OK in 1.0ms @ install/install.go:87(install.Install)

Thank you for your help!
PS: there is no tag "Forgejo" on Stackoverflow yet

"there is no tag "Forgejo" on Stackoverflow yet" Now there is. Please edit it and add information.

@phd already did the edit removing git and github. In general I think too many build failure questions get git (and github). Often there is no Git problem. The code was cloned correctly and everything.

Running the code with go run . -w $(pwd) in the console or adding the program argument -w $ProjectFileDir$ to the run configuration in IntelliJ did the trick.
